# Make Terminal highlight recognised code as I enter them in the terminal

Tags: terminal, colors, gnome-terminal

I have been trying to find what this feature is called. So, while using VS Code in Windows 10 I found that the "git" and "cd" commands are highlighted with yellow color as I type them. I was wondering how I can do it with my Linux setup.

Here's a picture.
[image: picture with yellow highlighted code]

What is this feature called? And how can I get my terminal to work like this?

Comment: I'm not sure it has a *name*, although some call it "command coloring" and others call it "syntax highlighting". Certain shells do this. zsh in particular has it [semi-built-in](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting).

Comment: @torek thank you!! can you post this as your answer so I can accept it? that link you shared really helped. I just have to now modify the colors to my liking.

Comment: Links don't count as answers, on StackOverflow...

Comment: @torek oh... what would be the next steps then to tag this question as answered?

Comment: You could self-answer it, or just close it, perhaps.